# Difference between Application and Service in Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm new to Dropwizard.  In the newest documentation, it refers to "Service" as the main entry point of any application.  But in the example code, it actually uses "Application".  I'm assuming that "Application" is a new name for "Service", since I can't find "Service" in the new source code.

I also noticed that the namespace has changed from "com.yammer" to "com.codehaus" to "io.dropwizard".  I'm assuming it reflects the evolution of the project itself.  Just out of curiosity, can anyone add some context to how this came about?

Comment: Can you share that newest documentation ?

Comment: @Manikandan take a look at http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/core/#service

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both the naming changes you cited are actually changes for the upcoming Version 0.7.  The documentation isn't up-to-date yet (and is actually the main thing holding back the 0.7 release according to the mailing list).

The current release notes can be found in the [master branch](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/docs/source/about/release-notes.rst#v070-snapshot).

- Upgraded to Java 7.
- Moved to the `io.dropwizard` group ID and namespace.
- Extracted out a number of reusable libraries: `dropwizard-configuration`,
  `dropwizard-jackson`, `dropwizard-jersey`, `dropwizard-jetty`, `dropwizard-lifecycle`,
  `dropwizard-logging`, `dropwizard-servlets`, `dropwizard-util`, `dropwizard-validation`.
- Extracted out various elements of `Environment` to separate classes: `JerseyEnvironment`,
  `LifecycleEnvironment`, etc.
- Extracted out `dropwizard-views-freemarker` and `dropwizard-views-mustache`.
  `dropwizard-views` just provides infrastructure now.
- Renamed `Service` to `Application`.
- Added `dropwizard-forms`, which provides support for multipart MIME entities.
- Added `dropwizard-spdy`.
- Added `AppenderFactory`, allowing for arbitrary logging appenders for application and request
  logs.
- Added `ConnectorFactory`, allowing for arbitrary Jetty connectors.
- Added `ServerFactory`, with multi- and single-connector implementations.
- Added `ReporterFactory`, for metrics reporters, with Graphite and Ganglia implementations.
- Added `ConfigurationSourceProvider` to allow loading configuration files from sources other than
  the filesystem.
- Added setuid support. Configure the user/group to run as and soft/hard open file limits in the
  `ServerFactory`. To bind to privileged ports (e.g. 80), enable `startAsRoot` and set `user`
  and `group`, then start your application as the root user.
- Added builders for managed executors.
- Added a default `check` command, which loads and validates the service configuration.
- Added support for the Jetty HTTP client to `dropwizard-client`.
- Added Jackson Afterburner support.
- Added support for `deflate`-encoded requests and responses.
- Added support for HTTP Sessions. Add the annotated parameter to your resource method:
  `@Session HttpSession session` to have the session context injected.
- Added support for a "flash" message to be propagated across requests. Add the annotated parameter
  to your resource method: `@Session Flash message` to have any existing flash message injected.
- Added support for deserializing Java `enums` with fuzzy matching rules (i.e., whitespace
  stripping, `-`/`_` equivalence, case insensitivity, etc.).
- Added `HibernateBundle#configure(Configuration)` for customization of Hibernate configuration.
- Added support for Joda Time `DateTime` arguments and results when using JDBI.
- Added configuration option to include Exception stack-traces when logging to syslog. Stack traces
  are now excluded by default.
- Added the application name and PID (if detectable) to the beginning of syslog messages, as is the
  convention.
- Added `--migrations-file` command-line option to `migrate` command to supply the migrations
  file explicitly.
- Validation errors are now returned as `application/json` responses.
- Simplified `AsyncRequestLog`; now standardized on Jetty 9 NCSA format.
- Renamed `DatabaseConfiguration` to `DataSourceFactory`, and `ConfigurationStrategy` to
  `DatabaseConfiguration`.
- Changed logging to be asynchronous. Messages are now buffered and batched in-memory before being
  delivered to the configured appender(s).
- Changed handling of runtime configuration errors. Will no longer display an Exception stack-trace
  and will present a more useful description of the problem, including suggestions when appropriate.
- Changed error handling to depend more heavily on Jersey exception mapping.
- Changed `dropwizard-db` to use `tomcat-jdbc` instead of `tomcat-dbcp`.
- Changed default formatting when logging nested Exceptions to display the root-cause first.
- Replaced `ResourceTest` with `ResourceTestRule`, a JUnit `TestRule`.
- Dropped Scala support.
- Dropped `ManagedSessionFactory`.
- Dropped `ObjectMapperFactory`; use `ObjectMapper` instead.
- Dropped `Validator`; use `javax.validation.Validator` instead.
- Fixed a shutdown bug in `dropwizard-migrations`.
- Fixed formatting of "Caused by" lines not being prefixed when logging nested Exceptions.
- Fixed not all available Jersey endpoints were being logged at startup.
- Upgraded to argparse4j 0.4.1.
- Upgraded to Guava 15.
- Upgraded to Hibernate Validator 5.0.1.
- Upgraded to Jackson 2.2.3.
- Upgraded to JDBI 2.50.
- Upgraded to Jetty 9.0.5.
- Upgraded to Liquibase 3.0.4.
- Upgraded to Logback 1.0.13.
- Upgraded to Metrics 3.0.1.
- Upgraded to Mustache 0.8.13.
- Upgraded to SLF4J 1.7.5.